# web3 ABI doesn't work to get contract ownership on Ethereum mainnet

Tags: python, ethereum, python-3.7, smartcontracts, web3py

I'm working on python with web3 APIs. I'm trying to get the ownership of contract deployed on ethereum mainnet. The best code I could text was the following:

```
from web3 import Web3

eth = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/9aa3d95b3bc440fa88ea12eaa4456161"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(eth))

abi = '''[
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "owner",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "constructor"
    }
]'''

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress("0x95aD61b0a150d79219dCF64E1E6Cc01f0B64C4cE"), abi=abi)
owner = contract.functions.owner().call()

print(owner)
```

But if I try to execute the code I get the following error:

```
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted
```

Maybe ABI doesn't work for this RPC, or idk what occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queried contract ([source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x95aD61b0a150d79219dCF64E1E6Cc01f0B64C4cE#code)) doesn't have the `owner()` function (nor public property `owner` that would autogenerate the getter function).

When you're trying to call a non-existing function, the EVM then tries to call the `fallback()` ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html#fallback-function)). But it's not there either, so the call fails.

---

A contract doesn't have to have an owner. It's "just" a widely used pattern, [described](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control#ownership-and-ownable) and implemented by OpenZeppelin and other open-source library authors.

Comment: you are right. then if i try with a contract with its owner it works successfully. thank you.